# What is this (pre-May 2010) fanfic that uses "Syndicates" to mean "Eyes"?

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction

This [TVTropes article](https://tvtropes.org/Main/AuthorVocabularyCalendar) mentions the titular fanfic existing, which is explicitly not the famous *Eye of Argon*.

> There used to be a sample from some unknown fanfic from before May
> 2010 — not the legendary The Eye of Argon; this one is even worse —
> being circulated and mocked on the Net which had prose so purple that
> it was practically unreadable; unfortunately, all the pages containing
> it seem to have disappeared. To give an inkling of what it was like:
> it referred to someone's eyes with the word "syndicates:" "syndicate"
> -> "circle" -> "orb" -> "eye."

I found this one-shot (["Bloody Puberty"](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/7155461/1/Bloody-Puberty)), but the date is too late as it's marked Jul 7, 2011

> Then, as her blueish emerald orbs met his azure, glowing **syndicates**, he knew they were finally in blissful love.

Comment: That style sounds like the Eye of Argon.

Comment: @Adamant - Yep, but it's not. Thanks. I gotta remember to say that it's not that.

Comment: Just to be sure, is "Purple Prose" meant to be about a work named *Purple Prose* or that it uses purple prose?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - From the linked article, it looks like the TVTropes writer just thought that the prose of the fanfic was [purple](https://jerichowriters.com/what-is-purple-prose/) rather than it actually being a story called 'purple prose'

Comment: There's Atlanta Nights by Travis Tea--collaboratively written by a group of SF authors as hoax submission to PublishAmerica.

Comment: @mkennedy - From what information I can dig up, the word "syndicates" does not appear in there at all.